# make a special delay in gui of java

Tags: java, swing

I've made this code in java, i wanna make a delay after this part of code, but when i use delay or sleep codes the whole code sleeps for the delay time but i wanna see this back ground changes in gui and then make a delay!!! so what should i do?(I use swing gui)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if (matrisBazi[i][j] == 0) {
            jb[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        if (matrisBazi[i][j] == 1) {
            jb[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        if (matrisBazi[i][j] == 2) {
            jb[i][j].setBackground(Color.blue);
        }
    }
}
jb[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {   
    click(s);
    }
});
```

my actionPerformed void is called before and its inside of click(); functions and is doing the process so how to add swing timer code to this void?!
i think the timer doesn't work until the click(); finished.

Comment: [tag:swing] tag added. This is the best way to inform folks what GUI library you're using.

Answer (score 4):

If this is a Swing GUI (you don't tell us), you'll not want to use `Thread.sleep(...)` as it will sleep the Swing event thread and put the entire application to sleep. Instead you'll want to use a Swing Timer.

Note that if you'll be incrementing a variable slowly, you'll not use a for loop, but instead will increment the variable directly inside of the Timer's actionPerformed method.

For example this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
  // do some animation using i
  Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
}
```

would be changed to:

```
new Timer(sleepTime, new ActionListener(){
  private int i = 0;

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (i >= MAX) {
      // stop the animation
    }
    // do some animation with i
    i++;
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: @user3125076: you'll want to read the tutorial as it is all spelled out there. Google will help you find the info. If you have specific questions about your code after you've tried it, come back and ask a new question with your code.

Comment: @user3125076: please see short example above. Also, please disregard Alvin's well-meaning but misguided answer as you should not use a `java.util.Timer` with Swing animation if you want to avoid thread errors.

Comment: you know i wanna do s.t that it could make a delay after the changing backgrounds and then go to some other function (not animation), i mean between two time changing back colors i have some functions that should be run!!

Comment: @user3125076: please clarify your latest post as I'm not sure what point you're making. Again, see the example of code I've posted, again, check out the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) (link provided).

Comment: a complete explanation:
i have a Othello game between AI and a player. when the player chosed his button the backgrounds changed and the AI turn function called so AI plays and change the BKs again but you just can see final result so i wanna make delay between player BKs changing an AI turn! :D

Comment: @user3125076: OK fair enough. You now know what tool you need to use, you have links to the tutorials. I wish you god-speed at finding a decent solution. Good luck.

Comment: and i should add i used actionPerformed void to get clicked btn before:
jb[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){   
               click(s);
             }
          });

Comment: @user3125076: Your current question has been answered -- You will want to use a Swing Timer to do simple Swing animations, and the implementation of this will be up to you. You know what tool needs to be used, and you will now want to study the references that are available about this tool. Again if you get stuck in your implementation, come back with a new question and your code attempt. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a Swing timer (javax.swing.Timer) because you have a GUI.
Read about it in this tutorial:
[How to use Swing timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Ah, @HovercraftFullOfEels is right. Sorry. Read this Java link on Swing timer. Swing GUIs are completely different: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html